# Validate string in a given format

Tags: javascript

Recently, I've been asked for the implementation of an interesting algorithm. I have a function (isValidString). It should return true if the given string is valid or not. The string pattern looks like a valid expression. My first thought was to use a regular expression, then
I've decided to collect string key occurrences in an object and check if it's even number and so on... but there are a lot other cases can be exist. Any thoughts how to implement this algorithm effectively? Thanks

Here is how it looks like:

```
function isValidString(string) {

}

//Patterns for the valid string:

isValidString('{([])}') //should return true
isValidString('{(([{}]))}') //should return true
isValidString('{[[()]]}') //should return true

isValidString('{[}()]}') //should return false
isValidString('{{}()]}') //should return false
isValidString('{(})[]}') //should return false
```

Comment: Ah the good old validating brackets assignment, hint: use stack for characters and it will be a piece of cake.

Comment: Do your expressions always have to look like a _mirrored_ String ? Are the only allowed characters `[`, `{`, `(` and their opposite? Does the length always have to be an even number?

Comment: Why 2nd is valid?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all of the requirements the function should abide by. Also, please include what you've tried.

Comment: You could convert the input into an array of characters with `.split('')` or use a stack, then continue with validation.

Comment: is the test case simply "is this string valid JavaScript syntax?"

Comment: @WillD I guess not, apparently just `()` is not a valid js syntax;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that "valid" are those string whose brackets are balanced and well-formed.

You can use the following function:

```js
const isValidString = (sample) => {
    const stack = [] // This is a helper stack we will push the characters
    // We start looping through the characters
    for (char of sample){
        // If its an opening bracket we just push it to the stack
        if (['(', '[', '{'].includes(char)) {
            stack.push(char)
        } else {
            // If we find a closing bracket we check if the previous matchs it as its opening bracket
            const last = stack.pop()
            // If doesnt match the previous bracket, we return false. We found a wrong formed bracket!
            // If it matches, contine looping
            if (
                char === ')' && last !== '(' || 
                char === '}' && last !== '{' || 
                char === ']' && last !== '['
            ) return false
        }
    }
    // If theres no characters left in the stack means that all opening brackets have been popped succesfully from the stack when we found its closing bracket
    return stack.length === 0
}

console.log(isValidString('{([])}')) //should return true
console.log(isValidString('{(([{}]))}')) //should return true
console.log(isValidString('{[[()]]}')) //should return true

console.log(isValidString('{[}()]}')) //should return false
console.log(isValidString('{{}()]}')) //should return false
console.log(isValidString('{(})[]}')) //should return false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        String exampleInput = "[{}]";
        System.out.println(" Response " + solution.isValid());
    }
    /**
     * Returns true the string is valid, else false.
     */
    public boolean isValid(String s) {
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0)  {
            return false;
        }

        Map<Character,Character> startEndElements = new HashMap<>();

        startEndElements.put('[',']');
        startEndElements.put('{','}');
        startEndElements.put('(',')');

        char[] elements = s.toCharArray();
        Stack<Character> store = new Stack<>();
        for (char element : elements) {
            if (startEndElements.containsKey(element)) { 
                store.push(element);
            } else if (startEndElements.containsValue(element)) {
                char peekElement = ' ';
                if (store.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!store.isEmpty()) {
                    peekElement = store.peek();
                }
                if(isMatchingElement(peekElement, element)) {
                    if (!store.isEmpty()) {
                        store.pop();
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;                    
                }
            }
        }
        return store.isEmpty();    
    }
    /**
    * Helper method to find if the characters form correct pair.
    **/
    private boolean isMatchingElement (char startElement, char endElement) {
        if (startElement == '[' && endElement == ']') {
            return true;
        } else if (startElement == '{' && endElement == '}') {
            return true;
        } else if (startElement == '(' && endElement == ')') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function isValidString(str){
    const matches = {
        "[": "]",
        "{": "}",
        "(": ")"
    }
    
    if(str.length % 2){
        return false
    }
    
    let len = str.length / 2
    str1 = str.substr(0,len)
    str2 = str.substr(len,str.length).split("").reverse().join("");
    
    return str1.split("").every((char,idx) => matches[char] == str2[idx])
}

console.log(isValidString('{([])}')) //should return true
console.log(isValidString('{(([{}]))}')) //should return true
console.log(isValidString('{[[()]]}')) //should return true

console.log(isValidString('{[}()]}')) //should return false
console.log(isValidString('{{}()]}')) //should return false
console.log(isValidString('{(})[]}')) //should return false
```

Comment: I know its not included in op test cases but pattern's like `{()[]}` should also return true.

Comment: @Shubanker I can only go by what OP has laid out, which is to match on a symmetrical string.